# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict', when dict used as a key for another dict

Tags: python, json, hash

I have this piece of code:

```
for element in json[referenceElement].keys():
```

When I run that code, I get this error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

What is the cause of that error and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

From the error, I infer that `referenceElement` is a dictionary (see repro below). A dictionary cannot be hashed and therefore cannot be used as a key to another dictionary (or itself for that matter!).

```
>>> d1, d2 = {}, {}
>>> d1[d2] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

You probably meant either `for element in referenceElement.keys()` or `for element in json['referenceElement'].keys()`. With more context on what types `json` and `referenceElement` are and what they contain, we will be able to better help you if neither solution works.

Answer (score 1):

What it seems like to me is that by calling the keys method you're returning to python a dictionary object when it's looking for a list or a tuple. So try taking all of the keys in the dictionary, putting them into a list and then using the for loop.

Comment: No. Thats not it at all. .keys() returns a list.

The problem is the ReferenceElement he's sending is forbidden (You can't use a dict as a key, likely a restriction to stop you passing itself as its own key, which would be.... absurd)