# Remove duplicates from nested list using list as keys

Tags: python, collections

I use to have two lists, `files` and `g_list` which were both regular lists. I wanted to remove the duplicates from `files` and have `g_list` match. I found this solution;

```
from collections import OrderedDict as odict     
od = odict.fromkeys(zip(files, g_list))
files, g_list = zip(*od)
```

I have since modified `g_list` to be a nested list, but now when I run the above code I get this `TypeError`:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 199, in fromkeys
  self[key] = value
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 58, in __setitem__
  if key not in self:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How do I remedy this? Or is there another way to do what I desire?

**Edit:**

Input:

```
files = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
g_list = [['x','y'], ['z'], ['q','r','x'], ['z'], ['x', 'r']]
```

Desired Output:

```
files = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
g_list = [['x','y'], ['z'], ['q','r','x'], ['x', 'r']]
```

Comment: Use a `tuple` instead. Can be as simple as `tuple(my_list)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict', when dict used as a key for another dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531941/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict-when-dict-used-as-a-key-for-another-dict)

Comment: Using a tuple doesn't remove duplicates. A `len(files)` before and after yields the same result.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of `files` and `g_list`, and what you want to have afterwards?

Comment: @p014k so if you just want to remove duplicates, use `set(my_tuple)` to remove the duplicates

Comment: I'd like to remove duplicates from `files`, but also remove those same indices from `g_list`. Would a `files, g_list = zip(*set(zip(tuple(files), tuple(g_list))))` or something to that effect accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows what you were trying to do, but without importing other libraries.

```
d = dict(zip(files, g_list)) 
files = d.keys()
g_list = d.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists cannot be used as keys in dictionaries as they are *mutable*, they can be changed, so they can't be hashed. Well, they *could* be hashed, but *that hash might change*. As a dictionary relies on hashing its keys to be efficient, hashes must stay constant. The solution, then, is to use a **tuple**, which is exactly like a list except that it's immutable. To convert a list `L` to a tuple, simply do `tuple(L)`.

Comment: [See comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928870/remove-duplicates-from-nested-list-using-list-as-keys?noredirect=1#comment55618814_33928870)