# List Comprehension of Pandas Columns Results in: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, list-comprehension

I've downloaded a Kaggle [Kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/ashishpatel26/1-43-plb-feature-engineering-best-model-combined) as a Jupyter Notebook file, that I am trying to run on my local system. The kernel works fine on Kaggle. However the following line (in cell 4) is throwing an error when I try to run it as an .ipynb file:

```
cols_to_drop = [col for col in train_df.columns if train_df[col].nunique(dropna=False) == 1]
```

The error returned is:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Based on this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531941/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict-when-dict-used-as-a-key-for-another-dict#4531954), I understand that a dictionary can not be used as a key in another dictionary. However, I am having trouble honing in on which bit of code actually represents a dictionary.

I have tried several alternate versions of the code, based on the format in this [article](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) on list comprehension.

```
new_list = [expression(i) for i in old_list if filter(i)]
```

However, they produce the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.Series.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) calls `pd.Series.unique` under the hood:

```
def nunique(self, dropna=True):
    uniqs = self.unique()
    n = len(uniqs)
    if dropna and isna(uniqs).any():
        n -= 1
    return n
```

[`pd.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) uses hashing, much like Python's built-in `set` under the hood:

> Hash table-based unique,
>   therefore does NOT sort.

At least one of the values in one of the series in `train_df` contains a dictionary. Dictionaries are not hashable. Therefore, you will see `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`.

To see which series include which types, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
type_dict = {col: set(map(type, train_df[col].values)) for col in train_df}
```

Here's a trivial example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 'a', 'b', 4, {'some_dict': 3}], 'B': list(range(5))})
type_dict = {col: set(map(type, df[col].values)) for col in df}

print(type_dict)

{'A': {dict, int, str}, 'B': {numpy.int64}}
```

To use `nunique` to count unique items, you then need to clean your data to ensure your dataframe does not include non-hashable values.